# Is there something like C's #define in ActionScript 2.0?

Tags: c, actionscript-2, c-preprocessor

I'm looking for a shorter way to write a big expression in AS 2.0, which I could accomplish in C by using #define. Is there anything in AS 2.0 that allows me to do that?

Comment: Can you give us an example of one of these "big" expressions.

Comment: char._x*1/40-1/2, i have to write this a lot of times in my code and char._x change during it

Comment: This is what functions are for...

Answer (score 0):

Someone found a way to use the cpp preprocessor on actionscript: [here](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2005/03/31/using-a-pre-processor-with-actionscript-to-define-constants/)

However, unless you have a very good reason and have already weighed the performance of doing it cleanly and found hardcoding significantly better, I would recommend just doing your expressions in a function (premature optimization is no good)